# Why doesn't help centre clearly say that "How to write code that does X?" questions are not on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close, new-users, help-center

I encountered a question that essentially asked "I want to create a userscript that does this and that. How to do it?". I follow the [userscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userscripts) and I see questions like this from time to time.

These question are typically closed as too broad or "*It's seeking debugging help but needs more information*". But I am noticing that this comes as a surprise to new users. After all,

- they did provide all the information that is needed to make the script or explain how to make it
- it doesn't seem broad to them, they know exactly what they need and it's usually not overly complicated (ie. it would take me 30 mins to do it).

I think this might feel to new users as there are unwritten rules that are bringing close votes and down votes on their posts.

Why doesn't the help centre address it? By having to explain it under such questions, we waste our time (writing comments and voting) and OP's time, since they took time writing a question and it wasn't at all clear that it's off topic.

Comment: How to questions (meaning not debugging questions in disguise) *are* on topic. Asking someone to design and produce your entire project for you is too broad, as the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) states: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Things that are in between may or may not be appropriate, depending on how reasonable the scope is.

Comment: *may or may not be appropriate* that's really confusing to newcomers, and me also. I am not comfortable that this is left to our judgement, as it really means what would pass one day gets closed the next.

Comment: I would posit that education is not a waste of time.

Comment: Usually a comment along the lines of: "Sorry, a good answer would literally require whole books. The problem is harder than you think and unfortunately out of scope for this site. But if you try and encounter smaller problems on the way, you can surely come back and ask them here." that I post if I find the problem interesting, seems to be received well.

Comment: We do not need to change the form of English OP uses, centre and center are both equally correct. It should be left at OPs preference. Please stop changing it from what they had.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

HOWTO questions are on topic. Heck, they're some of the most useful questions around!

What becomes problematic is when you ask for *too much*:

- How do I make a Facebook, but for dogs?
- How can I make a compiler?
- HOWTO build my own CPU?

(all those are based on real examples that've cropped up over the years)

Those are all answerable questions! But... They might require a book - or a library of books - to answer in depth. That's not really something we support very effectively here.  So we close them in the hope that the asker can narrow down their question to something that can be answered in 30,000 characters or less.

Comment: And _"how to write a userscript that does X and Y"_, while simpler than a social network for dogs (never mind cats); is still too broad (unless additional scoping was offered on the question), right?

Comment: Depends a lot on what X and Y are, @yivi. "Opens a file and uploads its contents" would be fine; "makes Slack usable and fast" might be a bit much.

Comment: At the same time, nobody is going to answer question that simply asks for 30-120 mins of writing a script. But what I can do in the future instead of VTC is to list things OP can google to put it together. Is that a valid answer?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica i still say VTC.

Comment: What if one of us could fit dog facebook in at the 29,000 character range though? Everything is just include library [x,y,z] these days!

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica No, that would not be a valid answer, but it could be a good comment. An answer needs to contain all necessary information to answer the question. A list of things to Google does not fulfill that requirement.

Comment: [Here's is a twitter clone in 340 lines of haskell](https://github.com/Gabriel439/simple-twitter/blob/master/Main.hs) so I guess "How do I make my own twitter" would be on topic ;p

Comment: @CindyMeister So a valid answer is writing the code for the OP? Could you or someone post an answer containing valid example how to answer and question?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica No, if the question is "too broad" then there should be NO answer. But if a comment with links or search terms can help, then that is OK. But such information does not belong in an *answer*.

Comment: Yeah that seems fair to me too @gman

Comment: My take on this is... If someone wants to write code, let 'em. If nobody does... Then the question eventually just disappears. @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @Shog9 That's a good point. I guess I got over-concerned about what to do about a question instead of just letting it be.

Comment: Without knowing that this question was asked, I've asked on **how to close** these questions with the new close reasons [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391950/589259)

Answer (score 13):

I think the problem with trying to explain to potential askers that their how-to questions need to be reasonably scoped is that many people have *no idea* how to determine what "reasonable scope" is.

I really don't think people are asking questions like that just to be annoying<sup>1</sup>. They're just that lost. Someone asking how to build Facebark *actually thinks* that someone will be able to give them an answer that will tell them how to do it. To them it's like "I'm just asking how to do *one thing*! How hard could it be?"

It's not possible to help someone like that by adding some more text to the help center. The fact that they're even considering asking that kind of question indicates that if they've looked at the help center at all, they haven't understood it. The most it would accomplish would be to have something to point to when they get upset that their question was closed, but that doesn't save anyone any time and even at that point there's still no guarantee they'll read it or understand it.

<sub>1. Maybe some of them are, but this won't help them either</sub>

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1425/ sums it up pretty nicely

Comment: This is a good answer... I always think of the kids on the guitar newsgroups years ago, asking which strings would let 'em play like Clapton. Sooner or later, someone's gotta tell 'em that it ain't the strings; there's just no other way. We should do our best to do so kindly, and... Accept that we'll always have to.

Comment: Have,an upvote for the Clarkson quote:)

Comment: This is _Dunning Kruger_ manifesting itself in its most visible, daily form. We can all sympathise because, for all of us, there are very many fields where we are entirely _uncomprehending_ of how much field-knowledge we lack.

Answer (score 3):

> These question are typically closed as too broad or "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information". But I am noticing that this comes as a surprise to new users.

There is a lot of interpretation that goes into close votes.

Too broad is perhaps the worst recipient of this behavior. New users *are* surprised when these close votes with too much available interpretation are used, because to be honest even the experienced community cannot fully agree on which questions they cover.

I believe that the list of close votes, as well as their wording, needs to be revisited in order to reduce the level of interpretation available in their use as much as possible. This may mean introducing extra close reasons or refining current ones, but would lead to less confusion by askers and less animosity towards close voters.