# How to handle code requests without "too broad" close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Previously direct requests for (sample) code could be closed with reason "too broad". That close reason has now gone it seems.

Let's list the current options, in **off topic**:

> It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

That cannot be right, as an "answer" is asked for, not an off site resource.

> It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

That's clearly not it either, because there isn't any code so there is nothing to debug.

and then there is the more generic close reason on the first page:

> **Needs more focus**
>   Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Possibly, but the main problem here is that the "problem" is often clearly specified. It's just that the person is too lazy to try themselves. It's not generic enough to to be useful to anybody else, which seems to be the opposite of this close reason.

---

Or is SO now a free for all code service, where anybody can send requests and hope they are "answered"? Should we just not put these questions on hold anymore? If so, how is that compatible with trying to be a knowledge base?

Comment: Please note that this question is specific to the *current close reasons*. Don't point to dupes where the close reasons predate the current ones please.

Comment: Actually, the close reasons seem to be all over the place.  I've opened the close dialog twice, and got two different sets of close reasons that are all different than the ones I saw yesterday.

Comment: This question seems closely related to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391806/why-doesnt-help-centre-clearly-say-that-how-to-write-code-that-does-x-questi), asked earlier this week.

Comment: I still go with "Needs more focus" which used to be "too broad". I see it the same way - if somebody is asking "Can you give me the code to control a nuclear submarine" that definitely needs to be less broad or more focused. It's otherwise unanswerable - nobody is going to sit and write an entire application here. If the question is "I want to control the headlights of a nuclear submarine" that's less broad than before but has numerous implementations which is too broad.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I really think that the "needs more focus" description doesn't fit though, even if the "needs more focus" part does. It doesn't clearly indicate to the user what is wrong with the question. An adequate answer? Seems possible, the task is probably executable after all. Multiple questions? Not really applicable. I'll use it until the next description comes along, I suppose.

Comment: To me "too broad" and "needs more focus" are kind of synonyms. If they aren't maybe the difference could be written down somewhere so I can adapt my internal model.

Comment: Insufficient (re) search hasn't been a valid close reason for a long time (was it ever). It's only a reason for downvoting. Is this question maybe a feature request?

Answer (score 3):

Considering that [I was the guy who helped get the verbiage for that close reason changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291819/175248), I was able to find it listed as "Needs more focus".

[image]

From what I can really tell of the close reasons, the title headers have changed on them but not the body/substance.

Alternative take:  if you can't find a suitable close reason for a given question, *perhaps* that's a signal that it shouldn't be closed?  While I do agree with you that *some* effort should be applied to questions, closing questions just because the "person is too lazy" (for a given definition of *too* lazy) isn't what closure is about; that's best left for downvotes.

Comment: If I'm asked by my employer to solve a specific problem I hope that it has "enough detail" to identify a specific **solution** as well. What would keep me from posting it here? For instance, I was just handling [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59226210/589259). I don't see any indication that the user was trying to solve this themselves (please don't vote on that question just because I used it as example).

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica:  Still not a reason to *close* it since it's not off-topic.  If you think it's a poor question, then downvote it.

Comment: Changing verbiage in close reasons is an endless task.  You're never going to find the perfect words to prevent people from occasionally abusing close reasons.

Comment: Well, no @RobertHarvey; trying to wordsmith something together to get people to stop abusing close reasons is a fool's errand.  My thrust was more along the lines of, "if this is *really* what it's meant to be, then let's word it so that it's in-line with that."

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, if that's not off topic then clearly any question without any effort from the asker is considered on topic, and we've now become **the** dump place for any **task**. If this is the entirety of your reasoning, then I want "too broad" back, as your close reason text is clearly itself not broad enough. If I downvote then I normally comment as well, *care to provide a good comment for that*?

Comment: Was this just a verbiage change or did the scope of the close reason change too? It just takes some time to relearn the names. Internally, I still call it too broad.

Comment: @Trilarion:  It *should've* been more of a verbiage change to be more in-line with what the scope *should* have been. But, I'm not so sure these days.

Comment: The FAQ post on dealing with homework questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/1328439 still lists "too broad" as a closing reason for questions that require untangling specific constraints set by the teacher before arriving to an answer. Probably this has to be updated.

Answer (score -5):

The accurate close reason would then most likely be *"is a duplicate of ...[the Q&A the OP could've easily found if he weren't too lazy to do some research]*".

Comment: That's sometimes the best action. But e.g. in the example I gave the question was not just to find a string, but also to perform additional actions, which are not covered by your duplicate. It's still probably the best action for the particular case, not sure.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find duplicates for the other requirements too.

Comment: Yeah, but how to close the question for all of them? That's the problem with this task, it contains multiple well defined *requirements* rather than questions.

Comment: Vote to close for one. Click on edit. Add further ones.

Comment: You can edit the duplicate list to add another question. If you have to add a lot of other duplicates to fully answer the question, then maybe it really is too broad.

Comment: ... but a long list of duplicates is still more helpful to the OP ... and that's why we are here after all ... to help people ...

Comment: I'm here to help people that have actually tried to solve their issues and have a *concise* question while doing so. I'm not here to answer homework questions, CTF challenges or actually perform the work for somebody that gets payed for doing it themselves. If it just comes down to "help people" no matter what they've tried, then **I'm out** (like about everybody at my beloved crypto site, I must say).

Comment: @maarten well then leave it to others maybe? Nobody forces you to answer each and every question.

Comment: No, because it fucks up the content of the site and I still need to read the "questions" that aren't closed by others. Worse than that, it actually encourages others to post their assignments here.

Comment: @maarten yeah, then close it maybe? Also I'm [totally with you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391947/5260024) on bad™ questions.

Comment: That brings me back to the actual question: I don't think the "Needs more focus" description is - uh - close enough to be the right close reason.

Comment: yeah well *duplicates* ... that takes a few seconds only (for such simple cases) ...

Comment: @JonasWilms "Click on edit. Add further ones." I don't think that everyone has that feature available to them...

Comment: @hereticMonkey but a goldbadger (which Maarten is for [tag:java]) do have that.

Comment: @JonasWilms Just trying to keep it clear for others who may read the thread and wonder what's up.