# Is this "Gimme-teh-Codez" Question suitable for a Triage Audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Actually, I *think* I understand how/why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59874756/10871073) was selected for use as an audit - simply that it <s>has</s> had multiple up-votes. Further, it *is* a well-presented and clear question, and has attracted a number of very good answers.

However, the question includes **no attempt** to solve the problem whatsoever and includes no code! Many such questions have attracted comments of the form, "S.O. is not a code-writing service!" and "What have you tried so far?" and are frequently closed as "Needs details or clarity" or "Needs focus."

So, when I came across it in the [Triage Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25314653), I selected "Unsalvageable" and would have given it just such a close vote; but ... I was rewarded with the ominous, "Stop! Look! Listen!"

I can swallow that, as it happens - no review ban or such (yet) - but I feel like I've been unfairly 'bitten' here. Or am I missing something important? (Always willing to learn from my mistakes!)

---

*EDIT: Things have changed a bit since I first posted this: the linked question has been down-voted to zero (currently) and closed. Now, although this was **not** the primary intention of posting, at least it will no longer be used as an audit (in that way)!*

Comment: You mentioned a few ideas in your question, but what close vote would you have selected if you had voted to close?  I don't work with python so would have skipped it myself, but I don't see any reason to vote to close that question as it seems clear and appropriately scoped.  Yes, it might be poorly researched, but that isn't a close reason (nor is "gimmie-the-codez")

Comment: @psubsee2003 How about this (especially the last clause): "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**." (But, I actually chose "Needs details or clarity.")

Comment: I may even have added a comment asking for some code - but that would also have failed the audit.

Comment: My opinion is that close reason is inappropriate.  The user isn't asking for debugging help so it doesn't apply (can't apply the last clause when it fails the first one).  I have to find the quote again, but a long while back Shog9 essentially said that asking for code itself isn't a problem as long as the question was reasonably scoped.  Lack of research can be a downvote reason (although that would have failed the audit too) but there is no close reason that applies to questions only lacking in research.

Comment: Note to self: "gimmie-the-codez" questions are totally fine if I do a half-decent job of formatting them. Thanks @psubsee2003 I'll remember that, makes my life much easier when I can just throw them to the StackOverflow coding service instead of needing to invest any effort on figuring it out myself.

Comment: This isn't the exact answer I was looking for, but this applies well in this case: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301064/how-do-i-handle-triage-no-research-cases/302067#302067  Now, I can't speak specifically as to where the question you are asking about fits into the 4 scenerios mentioned in that linked answer, but that is supposed to be the test for Triaging these types of questions

Comment: @psubsee2003 Many people have said that, including Shog9, multiple times. [Here's a recent one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391807/2734189). [Here's an older one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/2734189), with this quote: _"Trying to maximize effort actively subverts the purpose of this site."_

Comment: @CharonX "How-to questions are totally fine as long as they are reasonably scoped" is not the same thing as "'gimmie-the codez' questions are totally fine if I do a half-decent job of formatting them"

Comment: @pubsee2003: are the (undoubtedly wise) words of shog still relevant, as he has been ejected from SE? You might get in trouble too when following his lead.

Comment: No, they're still relevant, @usr2564301, as long as they make sense. Shog is still a *community member*, and even if he weren't, people are less important here than sound, logical arguments.

Comment: @usr2564301 I *did* read shog9's post, and I thought it was *very* relevant! However, no matter how 'wise' such word are, I'm still free (as an *equal* Community member) to disagree. Although I don't really 'know' Shog9, I feel that he would be happy to accept that disagreements do happen within this great Community ... that's kind of the point of the whole 'quorum' concept on things like close votes, down votes and other community-moderated actions.