# Do moderators face any consequences when wrongfully marking flag as unhelpful?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, moderators

I've recently been banned from flagging posts because some of the submitted flags in the last 7 days have been declined. However, reviewing them as suggested by SO, I noticed that of the seven declined flags, 6 resulted in closed posts, some of them being even heavily-downvoted (so I don't think the flag I raised was wrong).

Is there any action taken with moderators when they have clearly misjudged, the same way as we are banned from certain actions when not using the tools the right way? Or maybe the flag was not the right one? (I flagged as 'very low quality').

I read in a similar post (user asking why flag status did not correspond with post status result - declined flags resulting in closed posts and accepted flags resulting in non-closed posts) that one should not worry about the ban, because it's harmless and that if the question got closed, in the end, it achieved the desired result.

But I'd like to better understand how all this works to provide better value to the community.

Comment: *"so I don't think the flag I raised was wrong"* - That would depend on the type of flag, and the reason the posts were deemed unsuitable for SO.

Comment: If we're talking a bout close flags, that's not a case of mods declining the flag is it?

Comment: There should be a penalty for mods. Maybe ban then from handling flags for a while.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Off-topic flag declined because of strange reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261871/off-topic-flag-declined-because-of-strange-reason)

Comment: @gnat no, it's not the case.

Comment: @rene added an example as suggested.

Comment: Looks like a [triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27136321) got invalidated probably because the post got closed. I expect your flag to be linked to the triage review. Its non-positive outcome might have given you the declined flag. That still is weird but would explain. FTR: no diamond moderators seem to be involved in that question, at all, for what is publicly visible

Comment: @KevinB we're talking about low quality flags

Comment: That post needed to be flagged for closure, no need to raise a VLQ flag. Reserve those for gibberish posts.

Comment: @yivi The only flags available to me are Spam, Rude/abusive, needs improvement, duplicate, VLQ, and In need of mod. intervention. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Needs improvement" is the one you want. The labels were changed recently to make them "more friendly". In this case, that might have lead you into error. There is no perfect wording in any case, whatever was chosen was going to leave some users unhappy about the choice.

Comment: @rene What seems very odd. Sending a post to Triage results in a declined flag if the post is closed faster (outside the queue) than the queue resolution. If I understand that correctly?

Comment: @yivi Ok, I wouldn't have thought of that. If the question is very low quality, without any research or code provided, I assumed it was better flagged as VLQ than Needs improvement (sometimes they simply can't be improved, but should instead be asked as a totally different question). Now, that option has 5 more options (Duplicate, A community-specific reason, Needs detail or clarity, Needs more focus, Opinion-based), none of which seems appropriate for a question that should be closed. (btw, I'm reading [this help guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) also)

Comment: Unfortunately the dialog doesn't indicate that "needs improvement" opens up a new dialog. You can play around with the different options just to see where they lead on any post as long as you do not push the big blue button :) Note that "A community-specific reason" also opens up a new dialog..

Comment: Either "needs focus" or "needs details/clarity" would have worked for that one. It's not particularly important to overthink the specific close reason, there is some overlap and ambiguity in close-reasons, and that's intentional. The important thing is that questions that are not fit for the site are closed by the community. The flag you used needs to be evaluated by a moderator, and the "needs improvement" one by the community. One need to resort to mods when facing something the community can't handle on its own, or when greater expediency would be required.

Comment: Ok, I think I now better understand all this, thanks to you all! I really thought such questions were correctly marked as VLQ. One last request: is there any post explaining in some more detail when a question should be flagged as VLQ vs close?

Comment: *The flag you used needs to be evaluated by a moderator, and the "needs improvment" one by the community.* Oh, this really clarifies all my doubts now! Thank you!

Comment: You may try [When is a *closeable* question a *very low quality* question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-a-very-low-quality-question)

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344/11682469) by a mod might be useful. There's rarely a reason to flag a *question* VLQ. If you believe it should be closed, flag it as such ("needs improvement" etc.). It doesn't need to be handled by a mod but by the community first.

Comment: those 5 reasons are the reasons we have for "closure", if they don't fit... then it doesn't need closure, a downvote will do.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/1426539) by a former, highly esteemed community manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is a \*closeable\* question a \*very low quality\* question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357338/when-is-a-closeable-question-a-very-low-quality-question)

Comment: @StephenRauch it clarifies the things that were brought up later in comments, but it has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Watch out for the Spam flag. It has a very literal definition and the penalties for spamming are brutal. Be really sure before flagging spam. Also take care with the Not an Answer flag. Any attempt to answer is an answer, wrong answer, downright crap answer, and HOLY <expletive deleted>! DON'T DO THAT! are still answers, though HOLY <expletive deleted>! answers may need a custom mod flag if they're recommending harmful actions. In general, downvote (comment if necessary) and move on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question because it seems it's based on a false premise (that these flags were incorrectly handled).

But adhering literally to the question: unless one has reason to believe a mod is acting "incorrectly" with non-trivial frequency, it would make no sense to have "consequences" for the occasional flag-handling error by a mod.

Many mods are human, and thus make mistakes. And even when not making mistakes, they do have to make judgement calls and sometimes one can disagree with a mod judgement. That's fine.

But what kind of "consequence" would you imagine a mod suffering for making a mistake? Preventing them from doing their exception-handling job would run against the site's best interests. And besides, there aren't many options besides stripping their diamond from them, which would be incredibly severe and counter-productive.

If you encounter something you believe was an error in moderator judgement, more often than not you can simply shrug it off. It may have been an error, or maybe it was simply a difference in understanding. Or, as it was in this case, the error was not on the mod handling the flag.

If you believe the matter would benefit of additional clarification, you can bring up specific cases here in meta. This things serve to solidify consensus, so we can better adjust our expectations from moderation and so can have a more consistent moderation style in the future.

(And, if you really believe something is wrong with how a mod is acting during their duties, let me refer you to [this other answer)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401178/a-moderator-is-closing-a-lot-of-questions-that-i-think-are-on-topic-what-can-i/401182#401182)

Comment: "Many mods are human" :)