# Why was this opinion-based question reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, opinion-based, popularity

The question [How to use Git and Dropbox together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960799/12860895) is clearly ambiguous to answer and opinion-based, and this has been stated repeatedly in the comments:

> [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960799/12860895#comment34772468_1960799) said: *This question is unclear. What does it mean to use these tools together "effectively"? It's also too broad, and likely to generate opinionated answers.*

> [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960799/12860895#comment77214565_1960799) said: *The question is also somewhat ambiguous... Are you trying to avoid having a github/bitbucket account and instead having dropbox as origin? Or are you trying to keep the repos you have checked out at work and home in sync? I am actually looking for the latter. Does anyone know if its safe to keep the checked-out repositories under dropbox?*

Looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1960799/revisions), on *Feb 12 '14 at 8:50* which was almost **4 years** after the question was initially posted, the post was closed as "Not suitable for this site".

But *barely **6 hours** later the same day*, the post was reopened.

[image: Post closed]

[image: Post reopened]

This post seems very ambiguous and opinion-based to me. There is a myriad of ways the question could be interpreted, and the body appears to expect a simple "yes/no" answer with no context whatsoever. Why did it take so long to be closed, and then why on earth was it reopened the same day by different users?

[Questions which are off-topic but have historical significance are **locked**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/380081). Why was this post not locked?

Comment: Ancient history.

Comment: Also, 1142 upvotes.  Do you really want to wrangle a closure for a post that is that popular?

Comment: It has historical value, and it's also a target for marking dupes. So it would probaby be nice to have it open.

Comment: Questions which are off-topic but have historical significance are **locked**. Why was this post not locked?

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur It's not off-topic. It's just really old and popular. Closing such a question makes no sense.

Comment: @10Rep I said 'lock'. A question that is not appropriate for this site is still off-topic IMO, and there is a reason [historical locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/380081) were created

Comment: @10Rep Also, the best closure reason I can see is "Needs details or clarity", not duplicate.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 How? Why would it be closed like that? A how to question closed as "Needs details or clarity"? That makes no sense IMO, because "lacks research effort" has never been a reason to close a question. How to questions without too much detail are perfectly acceptable. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401157/12708583) answer for more detail.

Comment: Meta effect has closed the question now

Comment: Exactly what @Scratte Said. A moderator even quoted this same thing in SOCVR: I'm starting to become concerned that this room is somehow promoting the idea that all questions need to have an MCVE and/or that debugging questions are the only questions that are on-topic for Stack Overflow. That is not only wrong, it's horribly wrong, dangerously wrong. So I step in and correct this misconception as often as I can.

Comment: @10Rep If you're concerned about the SOCVR chatroom's beliefs about what questions are on-topic, you should raise them there or in a separate Meta question, not here. The room was not involved in the events described here, and we have rules about avoiding action regarding questions that're being discussed on Meta, as I've mentioned in the room already.

Comment: @Scratte You think the ideal questions for Stack Overflow are questions like "how to use two orthogonal services together effectively"? That's the scope of blog posts and tutorials, not a specific-Q&A site. The site's never been for that kind of broad, unspecific question.

Comment: That a question is popular, doesn't make it on topic.  that argument has caused so much pain over the years by new users seeing a "popular" question that is seemingly a great question and on topic because it's open and highly voted... only to ask their own and get broadsided with mass downvotes.

Comment: @TylerH I see it as a focused and clear Question. Perhaps "effectively" could be omitted. An objective would have been preferable, but a little late for that now.

Comment: @Scratte I've edited it out, lets see if it gets reopened.

Comment: @Scratte The two entities asked about are so broad that it would literally take a blog post or an entire blog series to answer the question completely, whether you include the word "effectively" or not. You can use git and dropbox for *so many things*. It is about as focused as a background on a website that is blurred for effect.

Comment: @TylerH If I may, I feel it should be historically locked. It may not be the best question now but in 2009, it was perfectly acceptable. That is the definition of Historical Lock, so I think that would be appropriate.

Comment: Just for the record: The post was reopened partly by a staff member.. though it's been a while.

Comment: I'd also like to emphasize that this question contributes a lot to our repository of knowledge. It's very good at SEO, since most begginers using Git would just google that. So why should it be closed, when it is useful/contributing to our repository of knowledge?

Comment: @10Rep [Because](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @10Rep I would agree with a historical lock, FWIW. You can flag the question for moderator attention and link to this meta post in the description along with such a request, and they may well grant it.

Comment: @yivi Fair point :D. But in 2009, things were different, and for such questions, there should be a historical lock, no?

Comment: @10Rep I’m fine with it being locked. But you were just arguing against its closure.

Comment: @yivi I'm compromising here :). Sometimes two parties gotta agree.

Comment: @TylerH I do not think I have said anything about it being "an ideal question". That felt like having words put in my mouth. I didn't find it very constructive. I also do not see the Question as being "How do I use git and dropbox separately"

Comment: it is a **good** question, with lots of good answers, most questions re a bit opion based

Comment: @Scratte You said it is the kind of post we should be keeping, and implied it is the kind of question this site is for. Another way of saying 'this is the kind of question this site is for' is saying it is an 'ideal' question. May not be an exact quote, but it's a perfectly accurate paraphrase.

Comment: @TylerH Then let me be clearer: It's not an ideal Question in my opinion. It could have been more specific, though is basically comes down to: "How can I have a git repository on dropbox?" However, I read some of the Answers, and learned something new. They seem to me to be largely in the same vein, not what I would expect from a "Primarily opinion based" Question. So, as a type of Question we want to avoid because we don't want discussions, I don't see it being bad. I even found it useful.

Comment: @nbk I agree :). And opinion based answers always have a basis of factual evidence in them.

Comment: Of the three comments you used to prove ambiguity, the first one is not about the question, but about another tutorial from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/how-to-use-git-and-dropbox-together#comment32929647_1960799). The second one  seems like a valid  criticism, but given 3 upvotes on the comment, Maybe only 3 users agree with that comment for like 7 years now.  The third comment is from someone  searching for a more specific question. In his perspective, It seems ambiguous during his search. Again only 2 upvotes on that comment.

Comment: None of the answers were opinions either. They all seem based on facts. Most of them have links to documentations.

Comment: @Scratte Being a prompt for things some people might not know about on some topic(s) that interest people does not make a post a good SO question.

Comment: "Why was this post not locked?" - probably because locking posts is not something that people like to decide on their own. The few times I have seen a post being locked, it was only after being discussed on meta first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a question from '09...
...before GitHub [really took off as a Git service giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_GitHub)...
...in an era where Dropbox and Dropbox-like services were dominant in mind-share...
...and developers and students who were getting off of CVS and Subversion who either didn't know much of the convention of a decentralized VCS or didn't have the infrastructure to host it externally needed a solution to share projects with their teammates.

I'm not exactly thrilled about the question quality, but it was asked in an era where its value was real and tangible.  There are a handful of groups out there that still want to use this workflow - as broken as it is - and the information in the question varies from useful to [intriguing museum pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037586/1079354).

I say:  historic lock.  It's definitely not a pattern that anyone wants to perpetuate, but deleting it would cause us to lose a lot of information out there that people have clearly been finding valuable.

Comment: I disagree that the workflow is "broken". AFAIAC, it's a matter of opinion. Some people think "How to" questions are more useful than "What's wrong with [so and so]" with a full MCVE.

Comment: @10Rep:  [*Clearly*, you haven't read the answers, nor have you experienced this firsthand.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215708/1079354)  I cannot express to you with symbols from the Basic Multilingual Plane how many times someone in my undergraduate courses has done this only to lose data at critical times.  Git stores things in the .git folder, and if that's messed with, you stand a very real chance of breaking your repo.  Adding to the fact that no one really understood "decentralized" or lacked the infrastructure, and...yeah, lots of hearts were broken doing that.

Comment: @Makoto We learn from the start make backups, make more backups and try to recover it at least once to test your strategy, every one who doesn't d this by hard, must pay for their mistake. Git is good,when teams must work together. like svn was on one source code

Comment: @Makoto I think we misunderstand each other. I was talking about the type of question, rather than the actual question content. I know nothing about .git, by the way.