# Why was this question comparing GNU grep's modes closed as not focused

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[What are the differences between GNU grep's basic/extended and PCRE regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926324/what-are-the-differences-between-gnu-greps-basic-extended-and-pcre-regular-expr)

To me this is a clear-cut question asking for the differences between different modes of a single program, but close-voters have not given me any details on why they think it is not focused.

"Needs more focus" close reason states:

> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

So what about my question is multiple questions in one?

Comment: "Not focused" is the new "too broad", and sometimes it's still used for the original reason (further reading: [Do we really need more focus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402523/2821954)).

Comment: How is the question too broad then? Is asking the differences between different grep modes really too broad of a question?

Comment: I am not really a subject matter expert here but I would say the documentation you yourself linked seems to answer your question? See: "_Perl-compatible regular expressions give additional functionality, and are documented in the pcresyntax(3) and pcrepattern(3) manual pages_" This seems to suggest that PCRE has some additional functionality compared to ERE and further tells what man page to look to for those functionalities.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ah but it does not specify what are the differences, which is the crux of the question.

Comment: Won't the additional functionalities themselves be the differences?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  the manpages for PCRE to my untrained eye look the same as the grep manpages, which is why the question is needed in the first place!

Comment: I haven't voted, but PCRE functionality is about an order of magnitude larger than BRE/ERE, so listing the differences is almost the same as answering "what can you do with PCRE", and a glance at the massive man page for `pcrepattern` would indicate that this is a broad question indeed.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you for being the first person to actually give me a reasonable answer to my question as clearly I am not a subject expert in this area. Feel free to post as an answer here.

Comment: I only knew of the superficial syntax differences which my question was based on

Comment: Another point I haven't seen brought up– I suspect people may be prone to miss your actual question since you've *only* included it in the title, rather than in the body. Perhaps that could explain some of the flags/ CVs?

Comment: It also reads to my untrained/ non-SME eye partially like you're looking to compare *three* things (GNU grep basic, GNU grep extended, and PCRE regular expressions), rather than *two* (GNU grep basic & extended vs. PCRE RegEx), which may also cause some voters to trip.

Comment: @zcoop98 that is a possibility. BRE/ERE to my knowledge are almost identical

Comment: I should clarify that PCRE is a mode within grep

Comment: Answers to such questions require high maintenance as they tend to get outdated quickly. I personally downvote and cast a close vote on those questions, because 1. I don't want to maintain such a broad thread, 2. I don't want to see that thread at the top every day. Both BRE and ERE are standardized in POSIX, you can just go read about them. And PCRE is a whole other world.

Comment: @oguzismail your responses don't make sense to me. 1. no one is asking you to maintain the answers, so not a valid reason for closure. 2. not a valid reason for closure.

Comment: Why'd you delete it?  It's technically still being discussed and it looked like there some reopen votes cast on it.

Comment: Fine, I undeleted it. But I thought it was just attracting negative attention at that point.

Comment: @qwr Well, to me they are. Because I know it is going to attract useless answers that'll only help those who can't be bothered to read a manual for some time, and then eventually get outdated. Almost all list this list that compare this to that questions are like that and they have no value & should be closed and deleted.

Comment: So I see that you've deleted it *again*.  If you're not interested in people advocating for your question or trying to get clarification on whether or not a question should remain on the site, could you not post it on Meta to raise its awareness?  The only thing worse than someone coming to Meta for help is for them to turn around and reject that advice out of hand.  You even said you could self-answer, which would've been great.

Comment: I was slow and missed my chance to self answer. But I deleted and reasked a new question where I got in a self answer. Idc if it's closed or downvoted I just wanted to self answer. Asking on Stack Overflow is like a chess game of political manuvering and being convincing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looking at a question *like* this, I usually like to seek out prior art that does a good job of not being tainted by either its age or its questionable topicality.

Seems like there's a decent number of practical questions asking for comparisons between two different and explicit things.

- [What are the differences between a HashMap and a Hashtable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40471/1079354)
- [What are the differences between .gitignore and .gitkeep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229885/1079354)
- [What are the differences between the urllib, urllib2, urllib3 and requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2018026/1079354)
- [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/1079354)
- [What is the difference between a URI, a URL and a URN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176264/1079354)
- [What is the difference between null_session and reset_session in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30582318/1079354) (my own question)

All of these questions have hallmarks we generally like:

- They're in-context and not philosophical; someone would benefit from knowing the difference between these.
- There's reason for ambiguity; examples or patterns may see one way, the other way or both ways applied in a code base with little rhyme or reason.
- There are advantages or limitations in choosing one approach over another.  Speaking strictly from a Java mind, using `Hashtable` is almost never preferred to using `HashMap` unless there were some really draconian concurrency requirements (and there are still probably better ways to do it even *then*).

In the context of grep, which is a ***very*** widely used tool, there are likely some circumstances in which using "normal" grep (e.g. no regex required) is disadvantageous to using grep with the extensions (e.g. `grep -E`) or using the Perl variant (`grep -P`).  There are some systems which still run using Perl that have assumptions about either the way data is shaped or the way data is parsed, and *perhaps* the Perl extension is the right way to query that.

So that said, I would find value in something comparing the feature sets of these two together.

- There's not much in the way of a hypothetical situation; there are some of us who do have to support older systems.
- There are likely major differences in support [as the man page suggests that there are some things that *may* be incomplete in the Perl regexp extension](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).
- There isn't a whole lot of shopping to do; no one is asking about which is *better*, but what the differences are, and that's long been a reasonable question to ask.

But I'm not an expert in regex, nor do I even want to play one on TV (doesn't pay well enough).  It's up to the community if they would want to support or answer a question like this, but from where I'm sat, I see no real reason *not* to answer the question.

Comment: I'm glad common sense still exists among some SO users. I have a self-answer prepared if my question is reopened.

Comment: Self answering doesn't exempt any question from quality standards @qwr